# How to make the matrix of colormap in full frame in Python Matploblib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

[image]I wanted to plot a Contact Map using the sparse.matrix feature along with colormap function from the matplotlib module of Python. I could generate the plot but the 2-D colormap condenses only to the left corner independent of x-range. How to make the 2-D colormap in full frame ? I used the following commands to generate the plot:-

```
trajectory_contacts1 = ContactFrequency(t1,switch1,switch2)
sparse_cm1 = trajectory_contacts1.residue_contacts.sparse_matrix
cm1 = sparse_cm1.todense()

with open('CM-pE42-Ab1-42.dat','wb') as f1:
    np.savetxt(f1, np.array(cm1), fmt='%.2f1')
    
# Import data from file
CM1 = np.loadtxt(fname = "CM-pE42-Ab1-42_Cluster-1.dat")

# Contact Map Plot for Ab1-42 & pE-Ab3-42

from matplotlib import cm as cmp
cmap = cmp.get_cmap('Spectral_r',50)
plt.matshow(CM1,cmap=cmap,interpolation='None')
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xlabel('Residue Number',fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel('Residue Number',fontsize=12)
ax.set_aspect('auto')
tick_params(bottom=True, right=True,labelbo[![enter image description here][1]][1]ttom=True, labelright=True)
plt.savefig("CM-pE42-Ab1-42_Cluster-3.png",dpi=300,format="png",bbox_inches='tight')
```

Here is the dropbox link for the .dat file:- https://www.dropbox.com/s/zqh4w541s6sohmj/CM-pE42-Ab1-42_Cluster-1.dat?dl=0

Kindly help me with the suggestions to correct the script to get the 2-D plot in full frame.

Comment: I downloaded your data and found the values in your file are almost all 0.001.  Therefore the plot may be no problem.

Comment: Yes, I solved it now. It was just choosing the xlim & ylim wisely. Definitely, the plot is not a problem but I wanted to just enlarge it. Thank you for your suggestions.